# Algolia sync with firebase doesn't work anymore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

Below you can see the console Output.

I am not using Firebase Freeplan. And the script worked fine till this week.

We added 3k new records to our database. Alle records are similar nothing special inside them.

```
Error when indexing contact into Algolia {
  name: 'RetryError',
  message: 'Unreachable hosts - your application id may be incorrect. If the error persists, contact support@algolia.com.',
  transporterStackTrace: [
    {
      request: [Object],
      response: [Object],
      host: [Object],
      triesLeft: 3
    },
    {
      request: [Object],
      response: [Object],
      host: [Object],
      triesLeft: 2
    },
    {
      request: [Object],
      response: [Object],
      host: [Object],
      triesLeft: 1
    },
    {
      request: [Object],
      response: [Object],
      host: [Object],
      triesLeft: 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you're using the Firebase Algolia extension try checking for extension updates on the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am getting the same error.  I have two functions: 1.) writes a record to firebase, and 2.) deletes the record from firebase.  I have an Algolia monitor that detects changes in the firebase database and updates the corresponding alogolia database.  While the firebase and alogolia databases are updated properly, getting this error message is annoying.  I was thinking about client.destroy, but then you have to re-init the index every time.